# Get possible combinations for array of objects by type and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I need to create every combination of objects possible out of an array with types/identifiers. E.g.:

Input:

```
let inputArray =
    [
      {
        'type': '1',
        'values': [
          'val1',
          'val2'
        ]
      },
      {
        'type': '2',
        'values': [
          'val1',
          'val2',
          'val3'
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Output:

```
let outputArray = 
    [
      [
        {
          'type': '1',
          'value': 'val1'
        },
        {
          'type': '2',
          'value': 'val1'
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          'type': '1',
          'value': 'val1'
        },
        {
          'type': '2',
          'value': 'val2'
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          'type': '1',
          'value': 'val1'
        },
        {
          'type': '2',
          'value': 'val3'
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          'type': '1',
          'value': 'val2'
        },
        {
          'type': '2',
          'value': 'val1'
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          'type': '1',
          'value': 'val2'
        },
        {
          'type': '2',
          'value': 'val2'
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          'type': '1',
          'value': 'val2'
        },
        {
          'type': '2',
          'value': 'val3'
        }
      ],
    ]
```

And it needs to work dynamically depending on the number of types, and values inside the input array. I.E. the input array has another object, where that objects values array has 3 or 4 elements...

What I tried:

```
function doTheThing(inputArray) {
  let outputArray = []
  for (let element of inputArray) {
    for (let value of element.values) {
      outputArray.push({ type: element.type, value: value })
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives me every value possible, but doesn't give me every combination that I need...

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-map-reduce-and-filter-explained-with-examples/ (you'll want to use map)

Comment: @NinaScholz done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create recursive function using simple `for` loop that exists when the value of `n` is larger then the length of the data or continues to increment it and then runs for loop.

```js
let data = [{"type":"1","values":["val1","val2"]},{"type":"2","values":["val1","val2","val3"]}]

function f(data, n = 0, prev = []) {
  const result = [];

  if (n > data.length - 1) {
    result.push(prev.slice())
    return result;
  }

  const { type, values } = data[n];

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    prev[n] = { type, value: values[i] }
    result.push(...f(data, n + 1, prev))
  }

  return result;
}

const result = f(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
```

Or you could use the `reduce` method instead of the `for` loop and make recursive call as long as the `n < data.length - 1`

```js
let data = [{"type":"1","values":["val1","val2"]},{"type":"2","values":["val1","val2","val3"]}]

function f(data, n = 0, prev = []) {
  return data[n].values.reduce((r, value) => {
    prev[n] = { type: data[n].type, value }

    if (n === data.length - 1) {
      r.push(prev.slice())
    }

    if (n < data.length - 1) {
      r.push(...f(data, n + 1, prev))
    }

    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = f(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks! I always forget about using recursive functions! This was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

This function can help us to extend a permutation:

```
let permute = (iterable, arr) => {
  let vals = [ ...iterable ];
  let result = [];
  
  for (let v of arr)
    for (let items of vals)
      result.push([ v, ...items ]);
  
  return result;
};
```

For example if we want to permute `[ 'a', 'b' ]`, `[ 1, 2 ]`, and `[ '?', '!' ]` we can do:

```js
let permute = (iterable, arr) => {
  let vals = [ ...iterable ];
  let result = [];
  
  for (let v of arr)
    for (let items of vals)
      result.push([ v, ...items ]);
  
  return result;
};

let v1 = permute([ [] ], [ 1, 2 ]);
let v2 = permute(v1, [ 'a', 'b' ]);
let v3 = permute(v2, [ '?', '!' ]);

console.log(JSON.stringify({ v1, v2, v3 }));
```

You can use this function with `inputArray` after performing a basic transformation on it (to achieve the type of result you posted in your question). For an entry in `inputArray` like `{ type: '1', values: [ 'v1', 'v2' ] }`, you need to convert that to a form like: `[ { type: '1', value: 'v1' }, { type: '1', value: 'v2' } ]`.

```js
// Your original data
let inputArray = [{'type': '1','values': ['val1','val2']},{'type': '2','values': ['val1','val2','val3']}];

// Function to format data as described
let format = arr => arr.map(({ type, values }) => values.map(value => ({ type, value })));

// The same `permute` function as before
let permute = (iterable, arr) => { let vals = [ ...iterable ]; let result = []; for (let v of arr) for (let items of vals) result.push([ v, ...items ]); return result; };

let formatted = format(inputArray);
let v1 = permute([ [] ], formatted[0]);
let v2 = permute(v1, formatted[1]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(v2, null, 2));
```

Comment: I went with Nenad's answer as it is more dynamic for me, but thanks for trying!